# Get specific template from elasticsearch via python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to get a template from AWS OpenSearch via python.

Now I know that from the Kibana it's:

```
GET _template/<template_name>
```

and from python, I have the function "search_template()" but it's forcing me to use the "body" parameter which I actually don't use in the kibana.

Does someone know how I can get the template?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably [`get_template(template_name)`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.17.9/api.html?highlight=search_template#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.get_template)

Comment: I'm using the OpenSearch library, and I checked the Elasticsearch library but I didn't see the option of "get_template()"

Comment: What client Python library are you using exactly (any link)?

Comment: [opensearch-py](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-py)

Comment: There you go, [it's there](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-py/blob/7874ed0e32c7640322054459ef7b334767110330/opensearchpy/client/indices.pyi)